# How to add copyright header to all scala files in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala

I am able to add copyright in java files but with same setup i am not able to add copyright in Scala file.

I have installed Copyright Tools using  **Help > Install New Software** and selected **Releng Tools**

I am using eclipse Mars.
Can any one help me to add copyright header in Scala file?